# Is there a closed-form maximum-entropy analogue of the exponential distribution, but restricted to integers?

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, maximum-entropy

I've used exponential distributions to estimate maximum-entropy probability distributions before.

Is there an analogue to the exponential that is restricted to integers? If so, does anyone have pointers to closed-form estimators for that distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrete equivalent of the exponential distribution is the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

[Wikipedia gives this as the maximum-entropy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Discrete_distributions_with_given_mean) under certain assumptions